# How to write our own marker interface in Java?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I know marker interface in java. It is used to define a specific behaviour about a class. For example, Serializable interface has the specific ability to store an object into byte stream and its reverse process. But I don't know where this specific behaviour is implemented, because it doesn't have any method in it.

1. How JVM invoke this specific behaviour?
2. How to write our own marker interface? Can you give me a simple user defined marker interface for my understanding?
3. Is it possible to have methods in marker interface?

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why do you want to write marker interface? It is kind of obsolete thing. Use _annotations_.... anyway what for would you use your own "marker interface"

Comment: @Op De Cirkel - Its definitely not Obsolete, First and foremost, marker interfaces define a type that is implemented by instances of the marked class; marker annotations do not. Read Effective java 2nd edition Item 37 for more details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Serialization is handled by the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` classes. If a class has special serialization needs, the methods to create are outlined in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Reflection is used to invoke these methods.
2. The same way you would write any other interface.
3. There's nothing stopping you from putting methods in a marker interface.

The more common practice now is to use [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) to provide the same metadata marker interfaces provide.

Comment: :thank you very much...i would like to know in which place they are writing code for relating ObjectInputStream class...?then only i can write my own marker interface like serilizable...

Comment: Go through the source of mentioned classes instead of asking exact lines!!

Comment: @Saravanan The JDK is open source. [`ObjectInputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java/?v=source). [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java/?v=source).

Comment: @Jeffrey nice answer :) but +1 for the comment `The JDK is open source` ;) :p

Comment: "The more common practice now is to use annotations to provide the same metadata marker interfaces provide." - Marker interfaces define a type that is implemented by instances of the marked class; marker annotations do not. Source: Effective Java 3rd edition Item 41.

Answer (score 39):

- How JVM invoke this specific behavior

`ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` will check your class whether or not it implementes `Serializable`, `Externalizable`. If yes it will continue or else will thrown `NonSerializableException`.

- How to write our own marker interface

Create an interface without any method and that is your marker interface.

Sample

```
public interface IMarkerEntity {


}
```

If any class which implement this interface will be taken as database entity by your application.

Sample Code:

```
public boolean save(Object object) throws InvalidEntityException {
   if(!(object instanceof IMarkerEntity)) {
       throw new InvalidEntityException("Invalid Entity Found, cannot proceed");
   } 
   database.save(object);
}
```

- Is this possible to have methods in marker interface?

The whole idea of [Marker Interface Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) is to provide a mean to say "yes I am something" and then system will proceed with the default process, like when you mark your class as Serialzable it just tells that this class can be converted to bytes.

Answer (score 7):

Yes We can create our own Marker interface..See following one...

```
interface Marker{   
}

class MyException extends Exception {   
    public MyException(String s){
        super(s);
    }
}

class A  {
    void m1() throws MyException{        
         if((this instanceof Marker)){
             System.out.println("successfull");
         }
         else {
             throw new MyException("Must implement interface Marker ");
         }      
    }   
}

public class CustomMarkerInterfaceExample  extends A implements Marker
{ // if this class will not implement Marker, throw exception
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        CustomMarkerInterfaceExample a= new CustomMarkerInterfaceExample();
        try {
            a.m1();
        } catch (MyException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Marker interface has no method. Java has built-in marker interface like `Serializable`, `Clonable` & `EventListner` etc that are understand by JVM.

We can create our own marker interface, but it has nothing to do with JVM, we can add some checks with `instanceOf`.

1. Create the empty interface

   ```
   interface Marker{    }
   ```
2. Write a class and implements the interface

   ```
   class A implements Marker {
       //do some task
   }
   ```
3. `Main` class to check the marker interface `instanceof`

   ```
   class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           A ob = new A(){
           if (ob instanceof A) {
               // do some task
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You might want to pay more attention, when you write code, because your code for point 3 has several mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

As explained very nicely in the Wikipedia article [Marker interface pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern), a marker interface is a form of metadata. Client code can test whether an object is an instance of the marker interface and adapt its (the client's) behavior accordingly. Here's a marker interface:

```
public interface CoolObject {
}
```

Then code can test whether an object is a `CoolObject` and do something with it:

```
if (anObject instanceof CoolObject) {
    addToCoolList((CoolObject) anObject);
}
```

The `Serializable` interface is defined as part of the Java language. You cannot implement behavior at that level yourself.

You can add methods to a marker interface, but that mixes the marker pattern with other conceptual uses for interfaces and can be confusing. (Is a class implementing the interface for the purposes of marking it, or for its behavior, or both?)

As explained in the Wikipedia article, marker interfaces in Java can (and probably should) be replaced with [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know marker interfaces get their behaviour by "utility" classes. For example if you have read the Design Patterns book by the Gang of Four, you have behaviour of a class tagged with a marker interface defined in another class.

For example you have a marker interface "Saveable". You have a process that traverses all classes implementing this interface (via reflection) and then does save operation on it.